# How to get config parameters in Symfony2 Twig Templates

Tags: symfony, configuration, twig

I have a Symfony2 Twig template. I want to output the value of a config parameter in this twig template (a version number). Therefore I defined the config parameter like this:

```
parameters:
    app.version: 0.1.0
```

I'm able to use this config parameter in Controllers but I have no clue how to get it in my Twig template.

Answer (score 423, accepted):

You can use parameter substitution in the [twig globals](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html) section of the config:

Parameter config:

```
parameters:
    app.version: 0.1.0
```

Twig config:

```
twig:
    globals:
        version: '%app.version%'
```

Twig template:

```
{{ version }}
```

This method provides the benefit of allowing you to use the parameter in `ContainerAware` classes as well, using:

```
$container->getParameter('app.version');
```

Comment: Good answer. Addendum: since Symfony 3.1 a variable must be quoted: "%app.version%"

Comment: @BigJ: Updated to include quotes, as this will also work in older versions.

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 190):

Easily, you can define in your config file:

```
twig:
    globals:
        version: "0.1.0"
```

And access it in your template with

```
{{ version }}
```

Otherwise it must be a way with an Twig extension to expose your parameters.

Comment: Better to set it in parameters like @Ryall explained.

Answer (score 93):

You can also take advantage of the built-in Service Parameters system, which lets you isolate or reuse the value:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    ga_tracking: UA-xxxxx-x

# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        ga_tracking: "%ga_tracking%"
```

Now, the variable **ga_tracking** is available in all Twig templates:

```
<p>The google tracking code is: {{ ga_tracking }}</p>
```

The parameter is also available inside the controllers:

```
$this->container->getParameter('ga_tracking');
```

You can also define a service as a global Twig variable (Symfony2.2+):

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        user_management: "@acme_user.user_management"
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html

If the global variable you want to set is more complicated - say an object - then you won't be able to use the above method. Instead, you'll need to [create a Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) and return the global variable as one of the entries in the getGlobals method.

Comment: This looks like the best solution because it keeps all the knowledge of system together.

Answer (score 19):

On newer versions of Symfony2 (using a `parameters.yml` instead of `parameters.ini`), you can store objects or arrays instead of key-value pairs, so you can manage your globals this way:

config.yml (edited only once):

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
  globals:
    project: %project%
```

parameters.yml:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
project:
  name:       myproject.com
  version:    1.1.42
```

And then in a twig file, you can use `{{ project.version }}` or `{{ project.name }}`.

Note: I personally dislike adding things to `app`, just because that's the Symfony's variable and I don't know what will be stored there in the future.

Answer (score 16):

The above given ans are correct and works fine. I used in a different way.

**config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: app.yml }
    - { resource: app_twig.yml }
```

**app.yml**

```
parameters:
  app.version:           1.0.1
```

**app_twig.yml**

```
twig:
  globals:
    version: %app.version%
```

**Inside controller:**

```
$application_version = $this->container->getParameter('app.version');
// Here using app.yml
```

**Inside template/twig file:**

```
Project version {{ version }}!
{#  Here using app_twig.yml content.  #}
{#  Because in controller we used $application_version  #}
```

### To use controller output:

**Controller:**

```
public function indexAction() {
        $application_version = $this->container->getParameter('app.version');
        return array('app_version' => $application_version);
    }
```

**template/twig file :**

```
Project version {{ app_version }}
```

I mentioned the different for better understand.

Comment: Yeah nice, this answer very well explains both ways: passing via the controller and passing it as a global twig variable! +1

Answer (score 15):

With a Twig extension, you can create a `parameter`Twig function:

```
{{ parameter('jira_host') }}
```

TwigExtension.php:

```
class TwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public $container;

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('parameter', function($name)
            {
                return $this->container->getParameter($name);
            })
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Returns the name of the extension.
     *
     * @return string The extension name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'iz';
    }
}
```

service.yml:

```
  iz.twig.extension:
    class: IzBundle\Services\TwigExtension
    properties:
      container: "@service_container"
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was worried I had to duplicate the parameter from the parameters file to the twig globals.

Comment: Nice, but it is not an unnecessary overload pull whole container to extension for one parameter?

Comment: I believe with Symfony 2, you cannot inject container parameters (which is now possible with Symfony 4/5)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply bind `$this->getParameter('app.version')` in controller to twig param and then render it.

Answer (score 0):

In confing.yml

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
  globals:
    version: '%app.version%'
```

In Twig view

```
# twig view
{{ version }}
```

Comment: giving access to the whole service container is not a good idea. the container is a service locator and it should not even be injected with dependency injection, so neither in twig

Comment: @PaulAndrieux just out of interest: why is this so bad if it is just done for some low-key variables?