# Add parameter in symfony2 twig asset function

Tags: symfony, twig, templating, assets

I have been wondering if it is possible to add a parameter for the asset twig function like this

```
#config.yml
...
framework:
   templating:
      parameters: 
         key: value
OR
twig:
   parameters:
      key: value
...
```

And in the twig file use asset like this

```
# twig file
<script src="{{ asset('/file/path', key) }}"></script>
```

And will regenerate

```
<script src="/file/path?key=value"></script>
```

I know i can create a macro to do this but i want to know if there are another way.

Thank for your reply

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get config parameters in Symfony2 Twig Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787895/how-to-get-config-parameters-in-symfony2-twig-templates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assets are generally static files and not dynamic scripts, are you sure you're doing the right thing? If you have an asset that accepts a parameter maybe it should be a in a controller with a route defined so you can act on it within code and a `{{ path('...', {key: value}) }}`

Otherwise, The only thing assetic lets you do is auto-append a version number to assets using [assets_version](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/framework.html#ref-framework-assets-version)