# Symfony2 - Checking if an image type exists

Tags: file, symfony, twig, jpeg, assets

I've been following an earlier post to check if an asset exists, which works great when using specific filenames.

[Symfony2 and Twig - Check if an asset exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898628/symfony2-and-twig-check-if-an-asset-exists?lq=1)

However instead of checking for a specific image filename, how do you check for an image type? (all files with the .jpg extension)

Example: *.jpg (which doesn't work neither does .jpg)

```
{% if asset_exists('/images/*.jpg') %}
    <div class="entry-thumbnail">
            <img width="230" height="172" src="{{ asset(['images/', post.image]|join) }}" class="" alt=""/>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you are using:

```
{{ asset(['images/', post.image]|join) }}`
```

Why not using:

```
{% if asset_exists(['images/', post.image]|join) %}
```

Tip: replace `['images/', post.image]|join` by using the [concat operator ~](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators): `'images/' ~ post.image`

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to modify the Twig Extension and replace `!is_file($toCheck)` with `count(glob($toCheck)) < 1`

[glob function (php.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)