# Symfony2 load css depending on template or controller

Tags: php, symfony

How can I make feature to load for example css files depending on controller

For example I have action registrationAction() which is method of AccountController.

I need to look at the bundle/sitebundle/css/Account/registration.css and if file exists import stylesheet !

Comment: How about changing the css in your view?

Comment: I want to separate this code and do it automaticaly. If file exists - load it. I'm new to symfony so I don't know better way to do it - via twig extension or via service (dependency injection)

Comment: You will probably find something here then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14232207/1443490

Comment: So, you think, Best way to achieve this goal is to extends twig and write code in a function.

Comment: That's a way to do it. I am not sure I fully understand your goal so it's hard to say if it is the best solution :) Do you have a case scenario?