# Symfony2 LiipImagineBundle default image

Tags: image, symfony, default, liipimaginebundle

I'm using LiipImagineBundle for an application built with symfony2 and I want to display a default image, when a image does not exists.
Let's say I have

```
<img src="{{ ('/profiles/foo.JPG') | imagine_filter('bar') }}" />
```

How could I display default.jpg when '/profiles/foo.JPG' does not exists?

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231967/symfony2-checking-if-file-exists

:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Martin Lie i have foud a link for you and i hope you will directly undeerstand the scenario because by default Twig can not test if a Phisicall object exists or not.. so you must create a service that will help you to make it directely in Twig...

[Create a service for twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231967/symfony2-checking-if-file-exists)

Don't worry !

Comment: Thank you. I will create this service.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but the correct (and probably easiest) way to do this is to specify a `default_image` in the liip-imagine configuration file.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

You test if the variable the image exist... 
for example is you have sent your image from a controller

just make:

```
{% if image is defined %}
        <img src="{{ image | imagine_filter('bar') }}" />
 {% else %}
        <img src="{{ ('/profiles/default.jpg') | imagine_filter('bar') }}" />
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, cobra18 - Thanks for your response.
My scenario is this: the name of the image will be the id of the user, which always exists. Is there any possibility to display a default image in this case (if the phisically image does not exists) ?

Thanks

Comment: This is ok, indeed! Thankyou Martin Lie!