# How to replace not found images in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Normally you would include images with

```
<img src="{{ asset('location') }}"/>
```

But if the image doesn't exist, a 404 is thrown and a broken image is shown. How to show another image instead of a broken one? Is there a way to do it in twig?

I'm also using [SonataMediaBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle) which shows images like so:

```
{% path media, 'small' %}
```

Figured there would be a way inside the bundle to check if the image exists, but it doesn't.

Comment: Yea, test that the file exists yourself, write a few lines of code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231967/symfony2-checking-if-file-exists

Comment: You should write your app that way that never show not existing images. Eg. if user don't upload images do `$user->setImage('default.jpg');` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try using onerror if you don't want to check the file's existence before hand

```
<img src="{{ path("image.svg") }}" onerror="this.src='{{path("image.png") }}'"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with rewrite. Create a .htaccess file in project directory. Add the following lines.

```
RewriteEngine On
<FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$">
    ErrorDocument 404 "/img/default-image.gif"
</FilesMatch>
```

**EDIT**

You can use `DirectoryMatch` for matching directories. Also you can nest `FilesMatch` inside it.

`<DirectoryMatch "^/www/xyz/">
   <FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$">
        ErrorDocument 404 "/img/default-image.gif"
    </FilesMatch>
</DirectoryMatch>`

Comment: This is good for general missing images, but what if I want different images in different twig files?