# How to access nested parameter values in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, parameters

I created a parameter in my parameters file:

```
parameters:
    category:
        var: test
```

I can access this in PHP by fetching it like this:

```
$var = $this->container->getParameter('category');
$var = $var['var'];
```

But how can I access this parameter in my `config.yml`? For example, I want to pass this parameter to all my twig files as a global twig variable:

```
twig:
    globals:
        my_var: %category.var% # throws ParameterNotFoundException
```

<sub><sup>*(**Sidequestion**:

I assumed I could access it via `getParamter('category.var')`, but got an error there. Do you know a nicer way than my two-liner? `$this->container->getParameter('category')['var']` works, but is a syntax error according to my IDE.)*</sup></sub>

Comment: have you tried category_var ?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that. Not working either.

Comment: here you can find answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839157/how-to-access-nested-parameter-values-in-symfony2

Comment: If you're using NetBeans just change `Project Properties -> Sources -> PHP Version` to higher, because function array dereferencing has been added in PHP 5.4 (and yes, NetBeans is smart enough to check it and tell it's "syntax error").

Answer (score 1):

`$this->container->getParameter('category')['var']`

..is actually a pretty good way to go. Which version of PHP is your IDE using for its syntax checking? Somebody please correct me, but I think this behavior was made valid in 5.3 or 5.4.

Comment: As for your second question, perhaps this will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787895/how-to-get-config-parameters-in-symfony2-twig-templates

Comment: I am using [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.org/). Thanks for your answer on the sidequestion, but I am more interested in the answer for the main question. The linked question does not help me as there are no nested parameters (but parameters with `.` inside...)