# Access to global parameters in Symfony2 and Twig

Tags: symfony, parameters, twig

I would like to search some parameters in my parameters.yml file from a template in twig, depending on a variable. I have tried the following but it didn't work:

**parameters.yml**

```
twig:
    globals:
        status:
            0: Paused
            1: Running
            2: Closed
```

**template.html.twig**
(game.status value can be 1, 2 or 3)

```
{% set var_status = game.status %}
{% set var_statustext = status.get(var_status) %}
<p>Status: {{ var_statustext }}</p>
```

Also I would like to access this parameters in the controller.
How could I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787895/how-to-get-config-parameters-in-symfony2-twig-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a way to access the *value* of the the global variable **status** (`type => array`) for a given *key* that is itself stored in another variable **game.status** (`type => integer/string` ).

Assuming `game.status` returns `1` ...

Then you can output **Running** using:

```
{{ attribute(status, game.status) }}
```

The [attribute function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) is what you're looking for.