# Symfony: How to handle config in Bundle

Tags: symfony, exception, configuration, twig, bundle

I'm having trouble finding the correct tutorial for me. I'm trying to have a controller-configuration in my bundle in `Resources/config/someconfig.yml`. I already adjusted it to a .`yml` extension. Now I'm searching a solution to access this configuration inside a twig exception controller (404-pages) and merge this configuration with the `config.yml` in `app/config/`.

Can anybody help me with a tutorial link or tips?

Thank you!

Comment: I am not clear on what is being asked for.  Possibly this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

To get Resources/config/someconfig.yml config you can create DI extension: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html

I think this can help you to get configuration value in view: [How to get config parameters in Symfony2 Twig Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787895/how-to-get-config-parameters-in-symfony2-twig-templates)

As an alternative you can override Exception controller (get configuration parameters there and pass them to the view): http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#replace-the-default-exception-controller

Answer (score 0):

For merging configurations among independent bundles you should use [`prependExtensionConfig`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.html#method_prependExtensionConfig) method and `PrependExtensionInterface` interface.

Documentaion page [How to Simplify Configuration of multiple Bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/prepend_extension.html) explains this technique in great detail.