# How to convert an integer based entity field into a human readable name in Twig

Tags: symfony

**In a Symfony 2.4+ project, what is the best way to register an array of values for a field that saves as an integer but needs to display human readable values in a template?**

I have an entity with a property that is populated with integer values that represent different constant values:

```
/**
 * The repetition frequency for billing cycle:
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
 */
protected $repetition = 0;
```

I would like to store the names of these values somewhere, so initially I put them in my entity with a getter:

```
protected $repetitionName = array(
        0 => 'Setup',
        1 => 'Second',
        2 => 'Minute',
        3 => 'Hour',
        4 => 'Day',
        5 => 'Week',
        6 => 'Month',
        7 => 'Year'
    );

public function getRepetitionName() {
    return $this->repetitionName;
}
```

This seems like a great central repository for the values.

Then in my twig template I don't want to display the integer, I want the corresponding name value. So I translate them like this:

```
<div class="billingCycle">{{ entity.repetitionName[entity.repetition] }}</div>
```

And in my form builder I make a field that references that array like this:

```
$builder->add('repetition', 'choice', array(
    'label'         => 'Billing Cycle',
    'help'          => 'The repetition frequency when this service is billed.',
    'choices' => $builder->getData()->getRepetitionNamePer(),
    // default to monthly (the most common)
    'empty_data'    => 6,
    'required'  => TRUE
));
```

### The Problems With This Approach

**1. Translation:** If I want to translate this at any point, it's hard coded in one place.

**2. Reusability:** If I have other entities that have repetition (e.g. event calendar) it would be nice to reuse this.

**3. Configurability:** Ideally these would be editable in a config file instead of the entity code.

### Alternative Solution: Custom Form Type as Global Service with Config Parameters

The better option seems to set some default parameters in the config file:

```
parameters:
    gutensite_component.options.status:
        0: Inactive
        1: Active
    gutensite_component.options.repetition:
        0: Setup
        1: Second
        2: Minute
        3: Hour
        4: Day
        5: Week
        6: Month
        7: Year
```

Then create a custom form type `Gutensite\ComponentBundle\FormType\RepetitionType` that loads the options from the config parameters. [See the Documentation for a great example of this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html). Then just refer to that field type like this:

```
$builder->add('repetition', 'repetition', array(
        'label'         => 'Billing Cycle',
        'help'          => 'The repetition frequency when this service is billed.',
        // default to monthly (the most common)
        'empty_data'    => 6,
        'required'  => TRUE
    ));
```

The inconvenient part of this solution, is that you have to either parameter to twig in your config (which is bloat for every template even if you don't need it), or always remember to manually pass the parameters to twig from your controller.

```
// I add to the standard object `$controller->view` which gets passed to Twig
$controller->view->options['repetition'] = $this->container->getParameter('gutensite_component.options.repetition');
```

To be accessed like:

```
<div class="priceValue label label-primary">${{ entity.price }}/<span class="billingCycle">{{ view.options.repetition[entity.repetition] }}</span></div>
```

This is more clunky than I would like but it is reusable. Maybe others have [better solutions to pass the configuration to twig than what is represented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787895/how-to-get-config-parameters-in-symfony2-twig-templates).

### Other Suggestions?

Do you have any other suggestions, best practices or lessons learned? Please share.

Comment: Just a proposal: what if you pass the IDs through the translator, like this: `{{ 'repetitionName'. ~ entity.repetition }}`? That would allow you to easily translate these strings (if this solution works, of course)

Comment: @kix I've not messed with the translator at all (yet) but I'll keep that in mind. I'm not sure how that would work in this case, where the "translations" would be store, and/or if it's meant to translate integers into human readable values. It's an intriguing suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to save those values as objects of a new entity and set a manyToOne relation from your `main entity` (or any other entity as your `calendar event entity`) to the `repetition entity`

If so, you can easily add new repetitions every time you want or get all objects of the `main entity` using any specific repetition.

Also you can build a nice form for a new object of the `main entity` with an input (human readable) of repetition values:

```
$builder->add('repetition', 'entity', array(
    'class'         => 'AcmeDefaultBundle:Repetition', // This is your new 'repetition entity'
    'property'      => 'repetitionName', // The field of your 'repetition entity' that stores the name (the one that will show a human readable value instead of the id)
    'expanded'      => true, // True if you prefer checkbox instead of a dropdown list
    'label'         => 'Billing Cycle',
    'help'          => 'The repetition frequency when this service is billed.',
    'required'      => true,
));
```

Now when you want to show the name of the repetition in twig you will use:

```
<div class="billingCycle">{{ entity.Repetition.repetitionName }}</div> (you can also translate that value later)
```

Comment: Ya, I like the idea of having this be another entity (logically it makes sense). But with some things that I *think* will not need to be edited (e.g. status = 1 or 0), it seems like a good idea to have these in settings rather than as another entity that requires a second database query (or join) everytime. This is a complex CMS and I really want to limit query count. Would you still recommend this method?

Comment: What do you mean a about 'limiting query count'? is your database limited about queries in your server? If not, I still recommend this method, working with a repetition entity. This way is cleaner than using parameters or having an array in the main entity (and is reusable even in diferent projects). Also you dont need a status field, cause if your main entity have a nullable property on the field of the 'repetition entity' you can know that if it's null, the repetition is not confgured for that user, and he should be asked if wants to set a repetiton or not.

Comment: Everything else, working with this relation is pretty easy in your controllers and templates, and you dont need to worry about 'queries or join' never. You only need your userObject and easily get the repetition: {{userObject.getRepetition}} and  $userObject->getRepetition(); (repetition getter have to return some value (maybe false) if $this->repetition is null.)

Comment: Correct, the framework will fetch the related entities for me without making me do any work. But it would still require a call to the database to fetch the values. Presumably that's where the values will be stored, right? That's one thing that I try to avoid when the data doesn't need to be dynamic. That's the main consideration here I think. But thanks for the input, it's a good option.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way (if you use it only for this entity) is to define a public method in your entity that returns you that array:

```
public function getRepetitionNames() {
    return array(
        0 => 'Setup',
        1 => 'Second',
        2 => 'Minute',
        3 => 'Hour',
        4 => 'Day',
        5 => 'Week',
        6 => 'Month',
        7 => 'Year'
    );
}
```

Another method to retrieve the label based by your "repetition" field value:

```
/**
 * @param $key
 * @return null
 */
 function getRepetitionLabel(){
     $repetitions = $this->getRepetitionNames();
     return isset($repetitions[$this->repetition]) ? $repetitions[$this->repetition] : 0;
 }
```

Will be much easier to access it in twig now:

```
<div class="billingCycle">{{ entity.repetitionLabel }}</div>
```

Last, in your form use your entity to retrieve the values:

```
$object = $builder->getData();
$repetitionChoices = $object->getRepetitionNames();

$builder->add('repetition', 'choice', array(
    'label'         => 'Billing Cycle',
    'help'          => 'The repetition frequency when this service is billed.',
    'choices'       => $repetitionChoices
    'empty_data'    => 6,
    'required'  => TRUE
));
```

If you plan to use it in more entities, you could use a interface.

Comment: The `getRepetitionLabel()` function is a great idea, but is adding this sort of "logic" to the entity frowned upon? It's convenient, but does it break the principle of what an entity is supposed to be for?

Comment: sure, the goal of entity is to handle the doctrine objects...not to define such static arrays