# Using an environment variable (from `.env` file) in custom Twig function in Symfony 4

Tags: twig, environment-variables, symfony4, twig-extension

How can I use an environment variable from the `.env` file in a custom Twig function (`\Twig_SimpleFunction`) in Symfony 4?

Comment: @jakub you might want to consider to change the "accepted" answer flag to lfjeff answer further down: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50422087/2008111

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's possible to access env vars in a twig template without any additional configuration:

`{{ app.request.server.get('MY_ENV_VAR') }}`

Comment: This works perfectly fine, but does not support defaults set in parameters:
`env(MY_ENV_VAR): someDefaulValue` would be ignore in this case.

Comment: Interestingly, this is not working for me in a docker container.  When I run the app code outside of the container it works, but with docker it doesn't.  The container _is_ getting all of the environment variables ... connecting to the container, I see that my var is present when I call `set`, but `app.request.server.get('MY_ENV_VAR')` isn't finding it.

Answer (score 108):

Here's an easier way (Symfony 4) that does not involve any custom extensions.  In my case, I wanted to set the Google Tag Manager Id as an environment variable in the `.env` file:

```
GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID="GTM-AAA12XX"
```

Next, reference the environment variable in the `config/packages/twig.yaml` file:

```
twig:
    globals:
        google_tag_manager_id: '%env(GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID)%'
```

Now you can use the tag manager value in your Twig templates like this:

```
{{ google_tag_manager_id }}
```

For a production system, you may not have a `.env` file.  In that case, set the variable in your Apache config file:

```
SetEnv GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID GTM-AAA12XX
```

I have not tested things with nginx config files, but I think this should work:

```
fastcgi_param GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID "GTM-AAA12XX";
```

For more details, see the Symfony documentation for [Configuration Based on Environment Variables](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#config-env-vars), and [Environment Variable Processors](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/env_var_processors.html). Environment Variable Processors let you do things like trim variables or set defaults.

Comment: This way worked for me for a docker container.  For some reason, `app.request.server.get('MY_ENV_VAR')` was returning a blank string, even though the env vars were all present in the running container.

Answer (score 17):

Install the [Dotenv component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html) so you can use the `getenv()` function:

```
<?php
// src/Twig/AppExtension.php

namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('my_function', [$this, 'myFunction']),
        ];
    }

    public function myFunction($varname)
    {
        $value = getenv($varname);

        // Do something with $value...

        return $value;
    }
}
```

If you just want to return the value of the environment variable, you can simplify the code like this:

```
<?php
// src/Twig/AppExtension.php

namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('my_function', 'getenv'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Either way, in Twig you can then do:

```
{{ my_function('APP_ENV') }}

{% if my_function('MAILER_URL') == 'null://localhost' %}
    Mailer URL not set!
{% endif %}

{# etc. #}
```

A better function name would of course be e.g. `getenv`. Here I used `my_function` so that our own code wouldn't be confused with the `getenv()` function provided by the Dotenv component.

The `getenv()` function returns `false` if the environment variable isn't found.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can do it directly.

`{{ app.request.server.get('APP_ENV') }}`

Answer (score 2):

Using DotEnv as well, I just went with:

```php
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader); // or however you access your Twig instance.
$twig->addFunction(
    new \Twig\TwigFunction('getenv', function ($key) {
        return getenv($key);
    })
);
```

And then in a template I'll just use `{{ getenv('SOME_ENV_VARIABLE') }}`.

Answer (score 0):

add it to your twig.yaml as a global variable like so, then you can use it anywhere:

```
twig: 
  globals: 
    env: '%env(SYMFONY_ENV)%'
```

Comment: Comment to myself though: This is apparently a bad idea, see the downvoted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787895/how-to-get-config-parameters-in-symfony2-twig-templates

Comment: could you clarify why that's a bad idea? IMHO, If you don't need access to this variable from service container, that should be fine

Comment: @nerdess I dont see why this is a bad approach, considering the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/env_var_processors.html). You are accessing `env` and only one specific paramter, not the `app` service container as statet in your linked answer.

Answer (score -3):

You can use it anywhere in the project like this

```
$_ENV["APP_ENV"]
```

Comment: Well it works? Why not? Also allows you to check the value and assign a default value: `$this->oauthGoogleId = $_ENV['OAUTH_GOOGLE_ID'] ?? '';`